# Overloading an Overridden method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class B that implements interface A such that:

```
public interface A {

    Map<String, Object> doStuff(Integer param1, Integer Param2);
}

public class B implements A {

    public Map<String, Object> doStuff(Integer param1, Integer param2) {
        return doStuff(param1, param2, newParam3);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> doStuff(Integer param1, Integer Param2, boolean param3) {
        if (param3)
            doSomething;
        return doneStuff;
    }
}
```

But when I try to access the overloaded but not overridden method I get compile time errors. Shouldn't this be perfectly fine?

Comment: "I get compile time errors" - which ones?

Comment: What are your compile time errors?

Comment: My wild guess would be you are trying to access `doStuff(1,2,3)` on a `A` reference, in which case it's prohibited since the method is not a part of the interface

Comment: OOOH, you're right, the reference is to the interface and not the implemented class. Wow good guess hah, i completely missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two entirely separated steps in java method invocation.

Step 1 is: Turn the method invocation (in your source code) into the fully qualified method ID. **This occurs entirely at compile time**.

Step 2 is: Now that we have a fully qualified method ID, find the actual *implementation* for this ID by doing a dynamic lookup, starting at the object's actual instance type (`x.getClass()`), and going upwards in the hierarchy until you find an implementation. **This occurs entirely at runtime**.

A fully qualified method ID includes the package, class, method name, **parameter types** and **return type**.

So, in your class B you have **2 different method IDs**. And different method IDs **are different methods**; the fact that the name is the same is irrelevant.

In other words, this:

```
A x = new B();
x.doStuff(param1, param2);
```

is stored as an INVOKEVIRTUAL/INVOKEINTERFACE to method `com.foo.pkg.A::doStuff(Ljava/lang/Integer;L/java/lang/Integer;)Ljava/util/Map;`. That's literally in the class file; have a look at the output of `javap` or actually go open that thing with a hex editor and you'll find that string in there, at least, starting at `doStuff`.

Then at runtime only, that 'INVOKEINTERFACE com.foo.pkg.A doStuff(Ljava/lang/Integer;L/java/lang/Integer;)Ljava/util/Map`bytecode instruction ends up checking the type of the object that your`x`variable is pointing to, figures out it's an instance of`com.foo.pkg.B`, and will then actually call B's implementation of this method to do the job.

Your second doStuff method has method ID `B doStuff(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;Z)Ljava/util/Map;` - note how this is just a completely different method (this one has a Z in it).

Thus, this:

```
A x = new B();
x.doStuff(1, 2, true);
```

is a compilation error: The A interface doesn't have that method at all.

Comment: This answer is too nice for a partially formed question :)

Comment: Both Andrew Tobilko and rzwitserloot are correct about the reference going to the interface instead of the implementing class. 

In my defense the class names for both are 50+ characters long, with the implementing class ending in "Impl" being the only difference between them X)